# Problem with bridge connecting to edges of face instead of round extruded part

Tags: faces, edges, extrude

I'm very new to blender, so sorry if I am asking a dumb question.
I have been following the Donut tutorial from Blender Guru and I'm now creating the Coffee cup.

The handle is done and I'm now trying to merge the last bit of the handle back into the cup. I have deleted the faces of the parts I'm trying to connect. But the problem I have now is that when I try to connect both with a bridge edge loop or pressing "F" with Vertices selected, the bridge doesn't connect properly. On the side of the cup it does so fine but on the side of the handle it tries to connect to the edges of the face instead of the actual part.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I know it's probably something dumb but I can't seem to find it. And nobody in the comments seems to have the same problem

Here is a link to the video:https://youtu.be/SBtDix7xGOg?t=365 with a timestamp of how it's supposed to look

Comment: hello, it's hard to understand what's happening, maybe share your file (before the bridge if possible): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: F does not bridge edge loop. That will make a mess.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zrgMyBkw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zrgMyBkw/) @moonboots Sure, here is a link to my blender file before the bridge.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I didn't know F wouldn't work, but I also did it in another way that wouldn't work either. After deleting the faces of both sides I want to connect. I just select those two parts i want to connect with alt left click and alt shift left click. Then i press f3 and type bridge. Then enter on bridge edge loop. So pretty much the same as Blender Guru does in his video. Only that my model ends up connecting to the edges like the images I posted instead of like a clean handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems:

- Overlapping vertices on the bottom and top of the cup handle, so select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to merge:

[image]

- Inner face on the top of the cup handle, it makes the bridge bad, so first delete this face loop:

[image]

- Then delete this face:

[image]

- Now bridge the top and bottom of the handle with the cup, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* instead of *LoopTools* to have a good result right away.
- The result is not good, it's because the normals of the handle are flipped as you see if you enable the *Face Orientation* option, so select the handle and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to fix it thanks to your help. I didn't even know Orientation was a thing really. But I'll be sure to look at it in the future if I ever encounter something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to *Edit Mod*e then press <kbd>A</kbd> to *Select All*.

After that press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>, then select *Recalculate Inside* and it fixed my problem.